# extract the row number of a function result

Tags: excel

I have a simple table with 5 names and 5 grades if you will.
In another column I order the grades using the LARGE function.
Now is there a way to know the row of each of the "ordered" grades to obtain something like that?

```
White      23        31       5
Red        15        23       1
Green      23        23       3
Blue       18        18       4
Grey       31        15       2
```

The column I can't calculate is the last one!

Comment: Are you trying to get the Row of the grades, so that you can retrieve that Name? Is there a reason that you can't use a sort (Select First Value in the Grades Column and sort Descending), as this would sort the value and retain the names next to the values? How do you know what 23 in your "ordered" column goes to `White` vs the one that goes to `Green`?

Comment: @user2140261 I don't know.. it's just an example to explain my problem better. Final goal is to write the names in the 4th column! The reason is that I want that from a formula!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the rank() function if you want to rank these grades. Not large().

```
=RANK(D2,$D$2:$D$6,1)
```

[image: RankExample]

Comment: I think what your calling `Grade2` is Grade1 Sorted Descending. So, overall is not needed. And because of that `Rank` won't give the OP that. And using `Large` 1,2,3,4 and so on by dragging down a formula is a completely Valid solution.

Comment: 31,23,23,18,15 are the Descending values of 23,15,23,18,32. Im not sure what order you are asking me to look at. Also, the OP isn't asking for the order of that grades, she only want the row associated to each grade. `In another column I order the grades`, then the actual question is `is there a way to know the row of each of the "ordered" grades` she already has the order she only wants to know what row each "ordered" grade is coming from.

Comment: @user2140261 I assumed he/she just did that to create a sample to explain his/her problem. Grade2 is sorted by descending value, that is correct. The overall grade order is needed though as far as I can understand him/her.

Comment: @Stepan1010 user2140261 is right. I just need the row! I use Large in order to get (possibly) the different rows if there are 2 equal values!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
=MATCH(LARGE(B1:B5,1),B1:B5,0)
```

The result is a number of row...

Comment: What about the Red, and Green both are 23. It will return the 1st Match only.

Answer (score 1):

In Cell D1 Put `=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C1,$B$1:$B$5,0))`

Then in Cell D2 put `=IF(D1<>INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+MATCH(C2,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0)))`

This will also work when duplicate `Grades` are present

But I Strongly Suggest using `Sort` as Follows:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

*****Also: ***** Here is the explanation on the above Formulas.

To get the Row that contains the Number we are looking for (the number in Column C) you need yo use the `Match()` Function. We enter `=MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0)` in `D1`:

[image: Match]

What this is doing: IS looking to the value in `C1`, this is `31`
It is looking in `Range("B1:B5")`, And 0 is for an Exact match.

So when look for a match to `C1` or `31` we get 5. This tells us that 31 is in `Row 5`

Now, to get the Value of `Column A` on `Row 5` we use `INDEX()` Function as Follows:

We add to the `=MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0)` in `D1` as `=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0))`

[image: INDEX]

This will look in `Range("A1:A5")` for `Row 5` (This is because  `=MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0)` = 5)
And the result will be `Grey`

Now if we drag this formula down we will find the first problem:

[image: Issue]

Here are our 2 Issues:

```
1)  We get an `N/A` error in the last row. 
2)  Although `Green` is only in `Range("A1:A5")` one time we see it twice
    even though it would seem that `White` should be twice.
```

These are cause because:

```
1) We need to add `$` to the range that will remain the same so when we drag down
   the formula is won't shift the range. As is the formula in `D5` is
   `=INDEX(A5:A9,MATCH(C5,B5:B9,0))` and we receive the error *because*
   `Range("A5:A9")` does not contain `15`, but the issue is we meant
    to look in `Range("A1:A5")`
```

So we change the Formula as so: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C1,$B$1:$B$5,0))`
Take note that we do not use the `$` on `C1` in the formula cause we ***WANT*** this value to change as we move down.

[image: Fix one]

But we still have the issue of double values when they shouldn't be there.

Because `D1` is the first cell we won't change the formula in it. As anything that is equal to the greatest value is simply tied with it and I don't see any reason why the order of the tie would matter.

Instead we will start in `D2` and enter `=IF(D1<>INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+MATCH(C2,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0)))`

What this is doing is checking if the value of `=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0))`
is not equal to the value in the row above. (being a sorted list means all double values would be on top of each other) and If it is ***NOT*** the same then use the value, but if it is the same we need to do a little more work.

If the value is not the same we use the Formula `INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+MATCH(C2,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0)))`

Now to explain it I will use our example of double values. In `D3` we find the formula: `=IF(D2<>INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)),INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)+MATCH(C3,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0)))`

And because we know that `INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0))` will be equal to the above cell (`White`), and we have gone over how the if true works, I will focus on the `if false` value of: `INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)+MATCH(C3,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0))`

We know `MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)` is the Row that contains the first instance of `C3` in this case `23` and the row is `Row 1` so we need to look for 23 in the row Under `Row 1`. So we use `MATCH(C3,INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)+1&":$B$5"),0)` which is equal to `MATCH("23", B2:B4,0)` because we are adding a `1` to the row that has the 1st match for `23` or `C3`.

that will now return us the Value of `2` as, the value `23` is in the second row of `Range("A2:A5")`, `Red` is in `Row 1` and `Blue` in `Row 3` of that range as shown:

[image: Row2]

but we don't want `Row 2` we know that `23` relates to `Green` and that `Green` is in `Row 3` So we add the row the we last found the value `23` (`1` or `MATCH(C3,$B$1:$B$5,0)`)to the row we currently found it (`2`) and get `Row 3`.

Comment: related either to my first example or to the table in the Stepan answer?

Comment: This will return the name matching to the Number in the "ordered" column in your original question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a full explanation to every thing I have discussed in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula approach based on the methodology outlined in [this link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/11/29/finding-the-2nd-3rd-4th-match/). The final layout of this approach is shown below.

[image: Spreadsheet layout]

I have assumed that there is 1 header row and I use 2 helper columns (D & E). While additional rows can be added to the header, the table must begin in column A in order for the formulas in column E to work correctly.

Although the helper columns could be eliminated by consolidating their formulas into the formulas in column F, I do not recommend it: the resulting formulas would be a pain to maintain.

**Formulas Needed**

```
  Cell C2: =LARGE(B:B,ROW(A2)-ROW($A$1))  [Copy down to bottom of data]

  Cell D2: =MATCH(C2,B:B,0)               [Copy down to bottom of data]

  Cell E2: =D2

  Cell E3: =IF(D3<>D2,D3,E2+MATCH(C3,INDIRECT("B"&(E2+1)&":B"&COUNTA(A:A)),0))
           [Copy down to bottom of data]

  Cell F2: =OFFSET($A$2,E2-ROW($A$2),0)   [Copy down to bottom of data]
```

**Explanation of Answer**

There are four steps to getting the answer:

- Sort the grades from highest to lowest (as you showed in your example data)
- Create a partial ordering of the row numbers for the sorted grades
- Get the row numbers for duplicate grades
- Use that ordering to show the name for each sorted grade

**Sort the grades from highest to lowest**

[image: Function to sort grade]

As you have done, my sort uses the `LARGE` function, which returns the nth largest value in a range or array. As shown, the `LARGE` function in cell `C2` takes the grades in column B. The "n" for `LARGE` is  calculated as the current row number minus the number of rows in the header, in this case the 1 row for cell `A1`. When the formula is copied down, "n" progresses from 1 to 2 to 3, etc.

**Partially order the grade row numbers**

[image: Formulas to get grade row numbers of sorted names, with duplicates]

The next step is to determine the row numbers for the unsorted grades that correspond to the sorted grades.

To do that, I use the `MATCH` function to find where each of the sorted grades lies in the list of unsorted grades in column B. `MATCH` takes three arguments--the value to be matched, the range in which to make the match, and optionally, the type of match, with a value of 0 or FALSE for an exact match--and returns an index number which represents where in the lookup range the match is found (1 for the first row in the match range, 2 for the second row, etc.).

In the formula for cell `D2` shown above, the `MATCH` function on the grade 31 returns 6 since 31 is in the sixth row of column B.

The result for cell `D4` shows why it is only possible to get a partial ordering with this formula. While we are trying to lookup the row for the second instance of a grade of 23, the formula returns a value of 2, which corresponds to the row for the first instance of 23. That's because `MATCH` will always return the first match for 23 it finds, which is on row 2!

**Get correct row numbers for duplicate grades**

[image: Formulas to get correct row numbers for duplicate grades]

The next step is to get the correct row references for the duplicated row numbers in column D. The formulas that accomplish this are shown for the first three cells in column E of the table.

There are three cases that have to be dealt with in column E:

1. For the first (and possibly only) instance of the highest grade, it is possible to just use the row number calculated in cell `D2`.
2. The second case deals with the first instances of the row references of the remaining grades. For these the rows numbers calculated in column D can again be used (via the `TRUE` branch of the `IF` statement in the column E formulas). For example, in cell `E2` -- which corresponds to the first instance of grade 23 -- the row number in cell `D3` can be used.
3. The final case is the rows for duplicate grades. Here, the `MATCH` for each duplicate in column B is recalculated using a sliding range that excludes the previous matches for that grade. For example, for the duplicated grade of 23 in column C, the match is on the range `B3:B6`, rather than the range of `B2:B6` used in the column D calculation.

**Diplay the names in sorted order**

[image: Formulas to show names sorted by grade]

This final step is straight forward: Get the name corresponding to the sorted grade. Here the OFFSET function is used; its arguments are a cell reference and the number of rows and columns from that reference that the desired value is to be found.

Comment: `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and should be avoided, that is why I used index. I would *not* use it in multiple different formulas that all reference each other. This also will have a big performance impact. Also why did you hard code `$A$1` and `$E$6` when referencing the row? It will ALWAYS return `1` and the `6` you then are adding and subtracting hard coded number with numbers that will ***ALWAYS*** remain the same. `ROW($B$2)-1` will ***ALWAYS*** result in `1` and `&":B"&ROW($E$6)` will always equal `B6` so why not just use the values instead of adding extra calculations?